# You MUST call Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(); prior to using it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, popupwindow

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>
> You MUST call Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(); prior to using it.

i already put Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init() in appdelegate.cs in IOS

but it still give me same error 
what should i do for it?

Comment: Please share your code. Where and how did you call Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init()?

Answer (score 5):

Simply, you need to call `Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();` on startup

**Andriod Example**

```
namespace HelloXamarinFormsWorld.Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "HelloXamarinFormsWorld", MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // !!!!!! here !!!!!
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication (new App ());
        }
    }
}
```

**IOS Example**

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

      // !!!!!! here !!!!!
      Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();

      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
      LoadApplication (new App ());
      return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
    }
}
```

Please read the documentation here

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started